# How to get the previous week number

Tags: java, date, time

I need to get the previous week number. E.g. This is week 38, I need to get week 37. How best to proceed?

```
int currentWeekNumber= now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int previousWeekNum = // How to get the previous week number??

    System.out.println("currentWeekNum = " + currentWeekNumber);
    System.out.println(" previousWeekNum = " + previousWeekNum);
```

Comment: Hmmm...how about `currentWeekNumber - 1` ?

Comment: currentWeekNumber - 1 ?

Comment: Would not work for you to mathematically just take one from the currentWeekNumber? Or you want to use only the Calendar?

Comment: It should not be like tht... if i use -1 for this week it works, then what about jan week 1... then current week will be 1 and if i do -1 then my whole code will bounce back. I want to get it from the calendar only

Comment: But it would be the only case. And you could use a method to check if it is week 1 and in this case you return 52 (the nr of weeks in a year).

Comment: @madhu No need  i guess.One if check will do the job

Comment: This question is more interesting & subtle than just a trivial subtraction! Please downvoters & quick answerers **consider more carefully**, because your quick answer is **wrong**.

Answer (score 5):

THis worked fine for me.... THis is the correct syntax to get it

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int currentWeek = now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println("current week = " + currentWeek);

now.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    int test = now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(" test date = " + test);
```

Answer (score 3):

`-1`  will work  right ?

```
 System.out.println("currentWeekNum = " + currentWeekNumber);
 System.out.println("previousWeekNum = " + currentWeekNumber-1);
```

Side note :Do not forget to check the current week is first week or not  :)

As the above solution is little vague  and as others pointed(you also found), Go for calendar's  add method,Which is more accurate.

```
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1); //Then use this instance.
int preveWeekNum = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: @Suresh currentWeekNumber-1 is previousWeekNum

Comment: Nope, this answer is unsound. It doesn't work reliably on the first week. As the OP says, you should use Calendar for the logic -- not pretend to do yourself, what Calendar is meant to.

Comment: Thanks @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ! ISO "week 01" is the week with the year's first Thursday in it (which ==) the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 Dec - 4 Jan. In every 400 years, 71 years will by this definition have "53 weeks". Logical in some way I'm sure, but glad I don't have to use the system :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 2):

The only correct way seems to be:

```
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
int previousWeekNum = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: Some years have week number 53, so only the second approach is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You are having currentWeek count. Then currentWeek -1 will give the previous week.

```
int previousWeekNum = 0;
calender.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
previousWeekNum = calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```